# asp.net site mobile phone support

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

I need to make my site work well on a blackberry, i haven't put too much effort into getting this working yet, but i have a few questions which google is struggling with.

I've read about detecting brower type and modifying the default behaviour of asp.net controls [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/browsercaps.aspx)

How would I go about supplying a differant stylesheet to a specific browser, should i just do this?

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToString() == "blackberry") //pseudocode
{
    Response.Write("bb.css");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("bb.css");
}
```

This will work fine, but i feel like there is a better method, i'm sure i've read about something in the past but i can't seem to recall.

I'm also considering a response.redirect to a differant page for a blackberry, which at the moment i would implemenet in a similar way.

Any thought or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

http://mdbf.codeplex.com/

Also nerddinner.com at http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: I do have to give the actual project a slight thumbs up, although it doesn't seem to be properly extensible: Mobile phones have almost 300 recorded varying features and properties so far and the amount is growing. For example that API in its current state won't be able to differentiate between the three different geolocation API:s currently available. Gah, I'm sounding way too negative here - I don't mean to.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is possible for a browser to pretend it's a different one (this was used e.g. by Opera which was by default set up to pretend it's an IE to overcome some restrictions on problematic sites). Personally I think the blackberry and similar devices are quite easy to detect so there's no reason to not do it like in your sample.. the site from Vivek looks good as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

While not directly related to your actual question, you may want to read what I wrote as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822325/content-management-system-targeting-mobile-devices/2036587#2036587) under the title *"Identifying the phone"*.

What you should really be looking for is a way to detect a feature of the current device and boy are you in for a lot of work if you want to do it properly. The problem as I stated in that other answer is that thanks to the history of user agent strings they haven't been reliable for a long time.

If mobile phones as a whole won't be your primary platform, you shouldn't dwell into this that much, find something that works such as checking if user agent string contains "Blackberry" and be satisfied with that. If, however, you really do want to do it properly, you have to develop a feature detection framework to do the job with all its possible combinations and permutations for you - there's no easy path when going down that road.

I'm sorry that I feel the need to be such a demotivator.

Comment: I guess i'm fortunate that, since it's an enterprise intranet site i only need to support the blackberry and nothing else, thanks!